# How to make bot respond to mentions more efficiently

Tags: discord, discord.js

I already got it down how to make the bot respond to a mention by doing message.mentions.has(bot.user)

But when someone pings everybody it will respond to that ping.

How do I make it so the bot responds only when the bot is specifically pinged, and not respond to external pings such as role pings, here pings, or everyone pings

Answer (score 0):

maybe `msg.mentions.first().id === bot.user.id`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
message.mentions.first().id === message.guild.me.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd want to do:

```
    if (message.content.includes("<@botidhere>") {
     //return;
  }
```